# Not all PHP session variables being set

Tags: php

This is what I do to set the variables

```
<?PHP
session_start();
?>
<?PHP
$user_name = $_POST['username'];
$first_name = $_POST['FirstName'];
$last_name = $_POST['LastName'];
$_SESSION['FirstName']=$first_name;
$_SESSION['LastName']=$last_name;
$_SESSION['UserName']=$user_name;
```

for testing purposes I printed out in this file before I set the Session variables so i know that I am getting the values from the form.
However when I go and print out in another like this

```
<?PHP
echo $_SESSION['UserName'];
echo $_SESSION['FirstName'];
echo $_SESSION['LastName'];
```

it crashes, after commenting out some of the prints i find that it only is setting the user name one and the others are lost somehow

this is from my form
    
    Login
    Username:  
    Password:

this is where I go to when submitted

```
$user_name = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$_SESSION["UserName"]=$user_name;
$_SESSION["Password"]=$password;
```

These is where I then try to print out

```
<?PHP
echo "username: "
echo $_SESSION["UserName"]; //this one works
?>
<br>
<?PHP
echo "password: "
echo $_SESSION["Password"]; //does not work
?>
```

my session variables are declared at the top of only one page like this

```
<?PHP
session_start();
$_SESSION["UserName"];
$_SESSION["Password"];
?>
```

Comment: just make sure you have `session_start();` on all of those pages

Comment: Show the form html code and also are you sure that the other 2 have data and aren't empty?

Comment: Just as @Ghost said, plus as you said *"is setting the user name one and the others are lost somehow"* - Most likely your form's elements do not contain a name attribute, and/or there's a typo, or lettercase do not match. `Username` and `username` or `Username` are not the same. Show your full code related to those. I suspect your form's elements that are not coming through are all lowercase.

Comment: If it's part of your actual code, `echo "username: "` and `echo "password: "` are missing closing semi-colons.

Comment: *"my session variables are declared at the top of only one page like this

<?PHP
session_start();
$_SESSION["UserName"];
$_SESSION["Password"];
?>"* - That's not good enough. You're not assigning anything. Use my edit in my answer instead then go from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *just make sure you have `session_start()`; on all of those pages  –  Ghost*

In addition to Ghost's comment, it could be that your form's elements do not contain a name attribute, and/or there's a typo, or lettercase do not match.
`Username` and `username` or `Username` **are not the same.** (PHP) **variables are case-sensitive.**

> *is setting the user name one and the others are lost somehow*

To elaborate on my comment, I suspect your form elements are all in lowercase or are not named.

I am ready to bet that if you change

```
$first_name = $_POST['FirstName']; // FirstName is not the same as firstname
$last_name = $_POST['LastName']; // LastName is not the same as lastname
```

to

```
$first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
$last_name = $_POST['lastname'];
```

that it will start working for you. Since, those are the two not coming through.

However, in order to be 100% sure, you will need to post your form's code, but am next to certain about my answer.

Your form should contain both:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname">
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="lastname">
```

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors if your system's settings are not automatically set to do so, which in turn will most likely be "Undefined index...".

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Now, if that still doesn't work, then you've a cache issue.

You can use `session_destroy()`. You can also unset the session, then start over.

For more information on these, visit:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php**

  > *Destroys all data registered to a session*
- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php**

  > *Free all session variables*

---

**Edit:**

Follow this and it will work, tested. You can then modify it after.

**First page:**

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
Username: <br><input type="text" name="username"><br>
First name: <br><input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <br><input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
<input type="submit" name = 'submit' value= 'Login'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

session_start();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST['firstname'];
$_SESSION['lastname'] = $_POST['lastname'];

echo "Username: " . $_SESSION['username'] . "<br>";
echo "First name: " . $_SESSION['firstname'] . "<br>";
echo "Last name: " . $_SESSION['lastname'] . "<br>";
?>
```

Comment: this should cover all bases. that `it crashes` is really vague. most likely this is just another case of `Undefined Index:`

Comment: @Ghost Really vague indeed. But I think you're right, "undefined index".

Comment: @Ghost Well, I'm off to lah-lah land. Keep the fort battened down tightly ;) *Cheers*

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back. Slept longer than i wanted to. All of my files have session start at the top. all of the text inputs have a name value, and they match(case sensitve) to the _POST in the other files.

Comment: @user3578388 Not a problem. Can you add your entire code related to it as an "edit" under your original question? This including your form.

Comment: @user3578388 I've made an edit that works. Reload my answer and look near the bottom under **Edit:**. This I've tested and working. You can base yourself on that.

Comment: ok so this works the same as I had before. All of these show up in the php file i got to when the submit button is pressed. But when I try to look at them from another page, only the username variable is saved.

Comment: Ok so i think i fixed the issue, When i was looking at them in the other file i put each look in a diffrent <?PHP section when i put them in the same it works. Thanks for all the help guys.

Comment: @user3578388 You're welcome, glad to see it got resolved, *cheers*